# COUNT WHERE two conditions are met in the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, count, having-clause

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't find a similar situation:

Given a table `'activity'`

```
user_ID | contact_channel_ID
123456    email
123456    email
555555    SEM
555555    SEM
995959    phone
995959    SEM
696969    email
696969    email
```

I need to count all users that have 'SEM' AND at least another channel IN `contact_channel_ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select user_id
from activity
group by user_id
having sum(case when contact_channel_ID = 'SEM' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when contact_channel_ID <> 'SEM' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

In MySQL, the `having` clause can be shorted to:

```
having sum(contact_channel_ID = 'SEM') > 0 and
       sum(contact_channel_ID <> 'SEM') > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select user_id
from activity
group by user_id
having max(contact_channel_id =  'SEM') = 1 
   and max(contact_channel_id <> 'SEM') = 1
```

If you want to count such users, then add another level of aggregation:

```
select count(*) as cnt
from (
    select 1
    from activity
    group by user_id
    having max(contact_channel_id =  'SEM') = 1 
       and max(contact_channel_id <> 'SEM') = 1
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by user and set the conditions in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM activity
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT contact_channel_id) > 1
   AND SUM(contact_channel_id = 'SEM') > 0
```

Or with EXISTS:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.user_id
FROM activity a
WHERE a.contact_channel_id = 'SEM'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM activity WHERE user_id = a.user_id AND contact_channel_id <> a.contact_channel_id)
```

If you want to count the users then change the above query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.user_id) counter
FROM activity a
WHERE a.contact_channel_id = 'SEM'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM activity WHERE user_id = a.user_id AND contact_channel_id <> a.contact_channel_id)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=df46f3b75ceb5f1bd4c85544fcc9bece).
Results:

```
> | user_id |
> | ------: |
> |  995959 |
```

and:

```
> | counter |
> | ------: |
> |       1 |
```